# I'm trying to access jq.mvc.min.js from the APP Framework, but it seems to be missing

Tags: model-view-controller, appframework

I'm trying to access the http://cdn.app-framework-software.intel.com/jq.mvc.min.js to implement in my app as described here (official documentaion):

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/docmvc.php#intro/quickstart

but it seems to be missing, maybe some had this problem and found another link ?!

EDIT : I found one here :
https://github.com/oreshinya/jq_mvc_test/tree/master/libs

but not sure if it is the latest version. still , would like to access the official one

Comment: That does indeed appear to be a bug.  I would report it to Intel.

Comment: You can get `jq.mvc.min.js`  from here: https://github.com/01org/appframeworkMVC